# Inserting a Word in Excel Cell At Specified Position

Tags: excel

In excel I have two columns A, B, C,D and E.In each row of column A, there is a paragraph. In the column B, C, D and E, there are four different words in front of each cell of column A. I want to PUT these 4 different words which are in column B, C, D and E into the paragraph present in column A cell. But all of these 4 words should be equally spaced throughout the paragraph. e.g 1 word should be in the beginning of the paragraph. And the rest of the three words should be equally spaced throughout the paragraph.

I have removed the leading and trailing spaces by applying "TRIM" function. The paragraph is composed of multiple lines with line breaks and multiple sub paragraphs.

Note: If  the solution is  flexible for more number of words e.g 7,8 or 9 words,then it will be great.

Comment: Can you post some code? You seem to have some solution going on already, posting your formulas/VB code (which one is it anyway) should help people answer your question more quickly.

Comment: please reword, with more detail and precision, your question. Currently it is not understandable. You say that you have "two columns"(?) with "four different words in front of each cell of column A"(?) you want the four "words equally spaced"(?) And please put some examples. And your code attempts.

Comment: I want to change my question in a different way.                                     In excel I have two columns A and B. In every cell of column A, there is a paragraph. In column B, each cell contains a certain word. I want to use that word in column B and insert in the paragraph in column A after 50 words in that paragraph in column A. How can I do this ?

Note: I want to resolve this problem through a formula or function. Afterwards I will drag that formula down in excel column.

Comment: If you want to change your question, edit your question; don't post a comment. And welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Following code might help. This is a [UDF](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel).

```
Function InsertWord(Source As String, InsWord As String, Pos As Integer)
    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(Source, " ")
    wordCount = UBound(arr)
    If wordCount < 1 Or (Pos - 1) > wordCount Or Pos < 0 Then
        InsertWord = Source
    Else
        arr(Pos - 1) = arr(Pos - 1) & " " & InsWord
        InsertWord = Join(arr, " ")
    End If
End Function
```

See image for reference:

[image]